# where is interrupt status flag of a thread in java , and why is interrupted() method static

Tags: java, interrupt

First question is : where is the **interrupted status flag** that interrupt() method supposedly  [sets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) :

```
 public void interrupt() {
            if (this != Thread.currentThread())
                checkAccess();

            synchronized (blockerLock) {
                Interruptible b = blocker;
                if (b != null) {
                    interrupt0();           // Just to set the interrupt flag
                    b.interrupt(this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            interrupt0();
        }
```

Second question is :
why is **interrupted()** method is **static** ? and **isInterrupted** not static ?

Answer (score 1):

The language specification doesn't dictate how the interruption status should be implemented. In hotspot, you can find the implementation details in the JVM code. For example, for linux, it's [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/37240c1019fd/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#l4143) around line 4140.

`interrupted` is static because it checks the current thread status. In other words, if you call `new Thread().interrupted()` on the main thread, you will get true if the main thread is interrupted, not if the new Thread is interrupted.

`isInterrupted` checks whether the thread on which you call the method is interrupted. In the example above, it would return the status of `new Thread()`, i.e. false.

Finally, an important difference between the two methods is that `interrupted` clears the interruption status. It is generally good practice to reset it, unless your code is responsible for the lifecycle of the given thread:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  //etc.
}
```